# Apache CXF attachement close stream

Tags: soap, cxf, mtom

I have came across this [blog](https://davekieras.wordpress.com/2013/05/30/apache-cxf-attachment-temp-file-leak/) that explains the need to close the `InputStream` of all the attachments that has been sent via `Apache CXF`. It also claims that such functionality is missing from the framework itself and hence it is the responsibility of users to close the `InputStream` of the attachment sent over the network.

I would like to know if this is still the case with latest releases (`3.1.x` and later) ? Also why does not the framework close the `InputStream` if it is just required part.

Please note that I have MTOM enabled and the attachments are always sent as MTOM.